# Error en CRUD generado por Symfony 5.4.* Object of class App\Entity\Cliente could not be converted to string

Tags: symfony, symfony5

Estoy intentando aprender a utilizar Symfony, no tengo nada de experiencia con este framework, pero sí tengo con Laravel.

He creado mi entidad Reserva, luego ejecuté `php bin/console make:migration`, posteriormente generé las tablas de base de datos en base a las migraciones con `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`, luego cree un CRUD (Controller) con: `php bin/console make:crud` que me generó todas vistas y el controlador con las rutas y los métodos, por último ejecuté el servidor con `php -S localhost:9000 -t public` y entré a `http://localhost:9000/reserva/` donde se me indica que no hay reservas. El problema es cuando quiero añadir una nueva reserva desde `http://localhost:9000/reserva/` es donde recibo el siguiente error:

```
Object of class App\Entity\Cliente could not be converted to string


<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ReservaRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ReservaRepository::class)]
class Reserva
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'date')]
    private $fecha_inicio;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'date')]
    private $fecha_fin;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'smallint')]
    private $numero_huespedes;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Cliente::class, inversedBy: 'reservas')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private $cliente;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Habitacion::class, inversedBy: 'reservas')]
    private $habitaciones;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->habitaciones = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFechaInicio(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->fecha_inicio;
    }

    public function setFechaInicio(\DateTimeInterface $fecha_inicio): self
    {
        $this->fecha_inicio = $fecha_inicio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFechaFin(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->fecha_fin;
    }

    public function setFechaFin(\DateTimeInterface $fecha_fin): self
    {
        $this->fecha_fin = $fecha_fin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNumeroHuespedes(): ?int
    {
        return $this->numero_huespedes;
    }

    public function setNumeroHuespedes(int $numero_huespedes): self
    {
        $this->numero_huespedes = $numero_huespedes;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCliente(): ?Cliente
    {
        return $this->cliente;
    }

    public function setCliente(?Cliente $cliente): self
    {
        $this->cliente = $cliente;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Habitacion>
     */
    public function getHabitaciones(): Collection
    {
        return $this->habitaciones;
    }

    public function addHabitacione(Habitacion $habitacione): self
    {
        if (!$this->habitaciones->contains($habitacione)) {
            $this->habitaciones[] = $habitacione;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeHabitacione(Habitacion $habitacione): self
    {
        $this->habitaciones->removeElement($habitacione);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Puede q te falte declarar la función __toString() en la entidad Cliente

Comment: ¿Debo declararlo en todas las entidades?

Comment: La función te garantiza tener de "forma automática" una representación en forma de texto de un objeto. No siempre es necesario.

Comment: @Francisco ¿es la forma correcta de solucionar este problema? leí por ahí que hay que indicar en un fichero de configuración que utilice un atributo del objeto por defecto.

Comment: Haber estoy asumiendo que te está dando ese error porque en tu formulario para agregar Reservas tienes un widget de tipo EntityType relacionado a la entidad Cliente. Ese tipo de campo en su configuración pide indicar cuál sería el atributo de la entidad que se comportará como value de los options y como texto en cda uno de ellos. Si no lo estableces explícitamente, se asume el ID de la entidad y el atributo incluido en el __toString(). Si no tienes esa función en la entidad, te saltará el error.